# error while connecting to snowflake via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, mule, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to snowflake via JDBC from mule and we are getting the below error.

: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:snowflake://cisco.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=XXXXXX&warehouse=XXXXXXX&db=XXXX&schema=XXXXXX&role=XXXX&CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=true&password=XXXXXXXXX

Error:-

[image]

[image]

Can some one help to resolve  the above issue.

: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver' for connect URL

Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Snowflake JDBC version used : 3.12.4

Comment: i am aleady having snowflake jdbc 3.12..4  jar in the code base

Comment: is it added to the pom.xml as a dependency and a shared library?
Which versions of Mule and the database connector are used?

Comment: its added in pom.xml and i am using mule 3 mesb version 3.8.4

Comment: Generic database connector i am using

Comment: Please add share the generic database connector configuration. Without credentials, of course.

Comment: Please post the loginformation and the full stacktrace as **text**, not as a screenshot. The most likely cause is that you don't have the driver on the classpath (or not on the right classpath!)

Comment: The JDBC url is already been shared in the question

Answer (score 0):

Please try below options

Option 1 -
Try both the minimum form (e.g. xy12345) and the full account name (e.g. xy12345.east-us-2.azure, but without .snowflakecomputing.com), making sure to not include the jdbc:snowflake:// string.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html

Option 2 -
Verify your driver version.
Download the driver ( if not ) as per steps and try again

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-download.html